# ReferenceError: MediabrowserUtility is not defined in magento wysiwyg

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

my question that i am using wysiwyg editor in magento admin side i checked every page every thing is right no error in code when click on the insert image they generate the error and can not works fine so help me anyone they face this type of error.  error is
"ReferenceError: MediabrowserUtility is not defined"
thanks

```
  $wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(array('tab_id' => 'form_section'));
  $wysiwygConfig["files_browser_window_url"] = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images/index');
  $wysiwygConfig["directives_url"] = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg/directive');
  $wysiwygConfig["directives_url_quoted"] = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg/directive');
  $wysiwygConfig["widget_window_url"] = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/widget/index');
  $wysiwygConfig["files_browser_window_width"] = (int) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/cms/browser/window_width');
  $wysiwygConfig["files_browser_window_height"] = (int) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/cms/browser/window_height');
  $plugins = $wysiwygConfig->getData("plugins");
  $plugins[0]["options"]["url"] = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/system_variable/wysiwygPlugin');
  $plugins[0]["options"]["onclick"]["subject"] = "MagentovariablePlugin.loadChooser('".Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/system_variable/wysiwygPlugin')."', '{{html_id}}');";
  $plugins = $wysiwygConfig->setData("plugins",$plugins);

    $fieldset->addField('question_details', 'editor', array(
      'name'      => 'content',
      'label'     => Mage::helper('supportportal')->__('Details'),
      'title'     => Mage::helper('supportportal')->__('Details'),
      'style'     => 'width:600px; height:300px;',
      'config'    => $wysiwygConfig,
      'wysiwyg'   => true,
      'required'  => true,
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to a missing configuration setting which is assigned to the WYSWIG `addField()` array.

If you open your Form.php simply add the following above the WYSIWYG field,

```
$configSettings = array( 'add_widgets' => false, 'add_variables' => false, 'add_images' => false,  'files_browser_window_url'=> $this->getBaseUrl().'admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/'));
```

Then modify your WYSIWYG form field (see highlighted below),

```
$fieldset->addField('post_content', 'editor', array(
    'name'      => 'post_content',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('faqs')->__('Answer'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('faqs')->__('Answer'),
    'style'     => 'width:700px; height:500px;',
    'wysiwyg'   => true,
    'config' => $configSettings
));
```

for detail you can see [this link](http://www.magentomonkeys.com/magento/magento-error-mediabrowserutility-not-defined/)  and also read some comments on that

hope this will sure help you

Comment: dear i am doing this before you can sent but they didn't full filed my requirements because i am using to enable the image but image wasn't work to upload.

Comment: $configSettings = array( 'add_widgets' => false, 'add_variables' => false, 'add_images' => false,  'files_browser_window_url'=> $this->getBaseUrl().'admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/')); i  true this things add_widgets,add_variables,add_images but not work.

Comment: pls check your folder permission and path

Comment: very strange for us. please debug it properly

Comment: you can add it to your post what have done so far.if my answer is little useful to u.pls dont forget to vote up and acpt